# Grid containing apples

Tags: c, algorithm, optimization, structure

I found this question on a programming forum:

**A table composed of N*M cells,each having a certain quantity of apples, is given. you start from the upper-left corner. At each step you can go down or right one cell.Design an algorithm to find the maximum number of apples you can collect ,if you are moving from upper-left corner to bottom-right corner.**

I have thought of three different complexities[in terms of time & space]:

Approach 1[quickest]:

```
for(j=1,i=0;j<column;j++)
    apple[i][j]=apple[i][j-1]+apple[i][j];
for(i=1,j=0;i<row;i++)
    apple[i][j]=apple[i-1][j]+apple[i][j];

for(i=1;i<row;i++)
{
    for(j=1;j<column;j++)
    {
        if(apple[i][j-1]>=apple[i-1][j])
            apple[i][j]=apple[i][j]+apple[i][j-1];
        else
            apple[i][j]=apple[i][j]+apple[i-1][j];
    }
}
printf("\n maximum apple u can pick=%d",apple[row-1][column-1]);
```

Approach 2:

result is the temporary array having all slots initially 0.

```
int getMax(int i, int j)
{
    if( (i<ROW) && (j<COL) )
    {
        if( result[i][j] != 0 )
            return result[i][j];
        else
        {
            int right = getMax(i, j+1);
            int down = getMax(i+1, j);

            result[i][j] = ( (right>down) ? right : down )+apples[i][j];
            return result[i][j];
        }
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Approach 3[least space used]:

It doesn't use any temporary array.

```
int getMax(int i, int j)
{
    if( (i<M) && (j<N) )
    {
            int right = getMax(i, j+1);
            int down = getMax(i+1, j);
            return apples[i][j]+(right>down?right:down);
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
```

**I want to know which is the best way to solve this problem?**

Comment: please define 'best'. quickest? least space used? most intuitive?

Comment: A mini bug in approach 2: if the apples array is totally empty, You get exponential runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's little difference between approaches 1 and 2, approach 1 is probably a wee bit better since it doesn't need the stack for the recursion that approach 2 uses since that goes backwards.

Approach 3 has exponential time complexity, thus it is much worse than the other two which have complexitx O(rows*columns).

You can make a variant of approach 1 that proceeds along a diagonal to use only O(max{rows,columns}) additional space.

Comment: The Grid is not guaranteed to be of size NxN. So, Will going across the diagonal be feasible?

Comment: Yes, it's feasible, but of course a bit more complicated. The diagonals you're using are given by `row_index + column_index == constant`. You start with the "diagonal" (0,0) and its apple-value, then `for(sum = 1, diag_len = 1; sum < N+M-1; ++sum) { /* allocate new diagonal of length new_len = min { 1 + diag_len, M, N } */ for(row = min(N-1,sum); row < min(M,sum+1); ++row) { col = sum - row; /* compare and store new value */ } }` (N is number of rows, M number of columns). I think the space savings are very rarely worth the effort to check you got everything right.

Comment: @DanielFischer take a look at my answer, rather than doing diagonals, you can just store a single column or row as temp. It's actually less complicated, and uses O( min{rows,columns} ) extra space.

Answer (score 0):

in term of time the solution 1 is the best because there is no recursie function.
the call of recursive function takes time

Answer (score 0):

### Improvement to First Approach

Do you really need the temporary array to be N by M?

No.

If the initial 2-d array has N columns, and M rows, we can solve this with a 1-d array of length M.

#### Method

In your first approach you save all of the subtotals as you go, but you really only need to know the apple-value of the cell to the left and above when you move to the next column. Once you have determined that, you don't look at those previous cells ever again.

The solution then is to write-over the old values when you start on the next column over.

The code will look like the following (I'm not actually a C programmer, so bear with me):

#### The Code

```
int getMax()
{
    //apple[][] is the original apple array
    //N is # of columns of apple[][]
    //M is # of rows of apple[][]
    //temp[] is initialized to zeroes, and has length M

    for (int currentCol = 0; currentCol < N; currentCol++)
    {
        temp[0] += apple[currentCol][0]; //Nothing above top row

        for (int i = 1; i < M; i++)
        {
            int applesToLeft = temp[i];
            int applesAbove = temp[i-1];

            if (applesToLeft > applesAbove)
            {
                temp[i] = applesToLeft + apple[currentCol][i];
            }
            else
            {
                temp[i] = applesAbove + apple[currentCol][i];
            }
        }
    }

    return temp[M - 1];
}
```

Note: there isn't any reason to actually store the values of applesToLeft and applesAbove into local variables, and feel free to use the ? : syntax for the assignment.

Also, if there are less columns than rows, you should rotate this so the 1-d array is the shorter length.

Doing it this way is a direct improvement over your first approach, as it saves memory, and plus iterating over the same 1-d array really helps with caching.

I can only think of one reason to use a different approach:

### Multi-Threading

To gain the benefits of multi-threading for this problem, your 2nd approach is just about right.

In your second approach you use a memo to store the intermediate results.

If you make your memo thread-safe (by locking or using a lock-free hash-set) , then you can start multiple threads all trying to get the answer for the bottom-right corner.

[// Edit: actually since assigning ints into an array is an atomic operation, I don't think you would need to lock at all ].

Make each call to getMax choose randomly whether to do the left getMax or above getMax first.

This means that each thread works on a different part of the problem and since there is the memo, it won't repeat work a different thread has already done.